# Retina MacBook Pro (non-Force touch) trackpad can't "click" as usual

Tags: macbook-pro, trackpad

I was working with my mid-2014 Retina MacBook Pro yesterday and everything was normal. Today, when I turned it on, I've noticed that trackpad is feeling a bit "weird". It's like, unless I forcefully touch the trackpad, it's not registering any click. It was much smoother and easy-to-press just yesterday, and it was just inside my hard-bag all the day, not damaged etc. It feels like it's a force-touch trackpad (while it's not), this is the closest I can describe how it feels. I can't get the regular "click" feeling and response from the trackpad.

What should I do?

Answer (score 1):

Nevermind. I started to press firmly all around the trackpad, and it just went back to normal. There was probably some dust particles in, and pressing around the trackpad eliminated them.

Answer (score 0):

Slightly bizarre but working answer that solved the trackpad problem for me ([per OSXDaily](http://osxdaily.com/2016/11/19/unable-to-click-mouse-trackpad-mac-fix/)):

> 1. Reboot the Mac as usual from the  Apple menu
> 2. When the Mac has booted back up, and assuming the mouse still isn’t clicking, close the lid and put the MacBook to sleep for about two minutes
> 3. Open the MacBook lid and use the computer as normal, the mouse / trackpad should click as usual again